# How to calculate (numerically) the convergence path to a saddle point

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, dynamical-systems, matlab, nonlinear-dynamics

Imagine the following dynamic system, characterized by two stable equilibria (A and B) and an internal saddle point (C) separating its two basins of attraction  of A and B.

clear all
syms x y a b c d e f g h i
Fx = a*x*(x - 1)*(d - (f*x + c*(i - 1))*(y - 1) + g*(x - 1) + y*(f*x - h + c*(i - 1)))
Fy = b*y*(y - 1)*(x*(h - i*(e + c - f*x)) - h*(x - 1) + i*x*(c - f*x))
par = {[a b c d e f g h i], [0.05 0.05 30 20 10 2 5 2.5 0.4]}

The phase plot for the parameters above is as follows.
[image]

How can you calculate (possibly even numerically) the only path converging at saddle point C (the one in green)?

Thank you to anyone who will try to help me.

Comment: You're looking for numerical methods for heteroclinic orbits. The technical term should help you find resources.

Comment: Maybe you want to compute the separatrix of the two basins of attractions?

Comment: @Ian Thank you I added the relevant hashtag.

Comment: @user10354138 Exactly, I want to calculate the curve separating the two basins of attraction of stable points A and B, which passes through saddle C and two other unstable points (1,0) and (0,1).

Comment: Analytically, you start with the computing the local stable manifold of $C$, and then flow backwards in time to get the separatrix (assuming closed form of stable manifold and separatrix exists).  Numerically, you can also compute this with shooting method or something like that.

Comment: Do you know of any example of a script applied to any map in Matlab that does something similar?